# PHP Get next result from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, controls, gallery

I have a database that stores image urls andother data, I want a gallery to display them but because the site is public I may want to delete some images. When a user uploads an image source and title, it is inserted into the database with an auto increment unique ID. The current script only adds or subtracts 1 from the ID to display the next or previous image. Is there any better way of doing this?
My current script:

```
function image_control($id){
$next=$id+'1';
$prev=$id-'1';
$query = "SELECT MAX(id), MIN(id) FROM mp_images";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $max = $row['MAX(id)']; $min = $row['MIN(id)'];
}
if($next==$max+"1"){$next=$min;} if($prev==$min-"1"){$prev=$max;}
echo "<a href='".$next."'>Next Image</a> <a href='".$prev."'>Previous Image</a>";
}
```

An example of this failing would be images where the ID's are 3,4,5,7,8.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: vascowhite is right, however his link to the article to learn more is not very helpful.  I found [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons) much more informative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

some pseudo code for getting the next id:

```
$nextId = SELECT id FROM mp_images WHERE id > $currentId ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
if ( no results )
  // no next image
```

and for the previous:

```
$prevId = SELECT id FROM mp_images WHERE id < $currentId ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
if ( no results )
  // no previous image
```

It's up to you on what to do if there is no next image (you could for instance fetch the first image) or no previous image (you are on the first image).

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how to fetch the next image after a break?
E.g. if it was on 7 and 8 was missing, how would I fetch 9?